# Displaying items in a query with no value

Tags: mysql

I have written the following query:

```
select title, branch_name, no_of_copies 
from Book_Copies BC 
inner join Book B on BC.book_id = B.book_id 
inner join Library_Branch LB on BC.branch_id = LB.branch_id 
where title = 'Grapes of Wrath';
```

But my issue is that this displays only the titles and branch names that have > 0 no_of_copies. How do I display ones that do not have a no_of_copies row? (Where it would be equal to 0).

Here is the table I currently get:

```
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
| title           | branch_name | no_of_copies |
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
| Grapes of Wrath | Central     |            5 |
| Grapes of Wrath | Allentown   |            2 |
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

This is what I need it to be:

```
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
| title           | branch_name | no_of_copies |
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
| Grapes of Wrath | Central     |            5 |
| Grapes of Wrath | Allentown   |            2 |
| Grapes of Wrath | Sharpstown  |            0 |
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: without seeing the tables we cannot fix your query but you need to use a left join and not a join to have all the items from left tables and a result from the right one only if it match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `outer join` instead starting from the `book` table.  Perhaps something like this:

```
select title, branch_name, no_of_copies 
from Book B
    left join Book_Copies BC on BC.book_id = B.book_id 
    left join Library_Branch LB on BC.branch_id = LB.branch_id 
where title = 'Grapes of Wrath';
```

---

Reading your comments, it sounds like you want to use a `cross join` between `book` and `library_branch` to get all combinations of books and branches (otherwise known as a `cartesian product`).  Then `outer join` those results to the lookup table:

```
select title, branch_name, coalesce(no_of_copies,0) copies
from Book B 
    cross join Library_Branch LB
    left join Book_Copies BC on BC.book_id = B.book_id 
                            and BC.branch_id = LB.branch_id 
where title = 'Grapes of Wrath';
```

Comment: I got the same result :/

Comment: @TheBandit -- please post your table structure, sample data and expected results.  If the above query doesn't work with an `outer join`, are you sure your `book` table has a record with `title = 'Grapes of Wrath'`?

Comment: Yes it does have that, I edited my question with the current and expected table

Comment: @TheBandit -- if your `library_branch` table does not have a row for that missing branch, how do you expect to get it?  Do you have a `branches` table as well?  Perhaps you want a `cross join` between `book` and `branches` to get all combinations.  Then you can `outer join` to get the 0 results.  Still difficult without posting your table schema and sample data from those tables.

Comment: my library_branch table does have a row for it.
library_branch has rows branch_id, branch_name, and address;
book has book_id, title, and publisher_name;
book_copies has book_id, branch_id, and no_of_copies;

Comment: @TheBandit -- editing with what I think you might be after using a `cross join`.

Comment: Thank you that worked, what exactly does the "coalesce(no_of_copies,0) copies" do though? I don't quite understand why this works.

Comment: @TheBandit -- `coalesce` is used to replace `null` values with the next value.  So since `no_of_copies` is `null` for that book/branch, `coalesce` changes it to 0 for display.